# Why doesn't Vista remember my folder display settings?

Tags: windows-7

I have this really annoying problem with Vista where folders seem to have different display settings every time I open them. (Display meaning "list", "detail", etc)

I have "Remember each folder's view settings" checked. Is there a setting somewhere else that is making Vista forget my settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Fix Vista Unable or Fail to Remember or Save Folder Types/Views Setting Error by Increasing BagMRU Cache Memory Size](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/11/08/fix-vista-unable-or-fail-to-remember-or-save-folder-typesviews-setting-error-by-increasing-bagmru-cache-memory-size/)**